# Draw persistent grid in TabPage (.Net, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, grid, drawing, system.drawing

I need to display a persistent grid in a TabPage. My problems would be instantly solved if I could draw to the entire non-visible portion of the TabPage and prevent graphics from being erased when scrolling.

The only other solution I can think of is tracking the scroll position in the tab and basing the grid drawn from that.

To get this to draw in the first place, I had to create an EventHandler for TabPage.Paint.

```
    //Code removed
```

This method draws vertical and horizontal lines to create a grid within the visible tab, but it continues to draw whenever a Paint event occurs (i.e. scrolling), so it creates overlapping lines and aren't aligned to anything but the size of the current visible area of the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that this solution is just pseudo. You also have to respond to scrolling.

```
void form_draw()
{
        spacingX = offsetX % scale * -1;
        spacingY = offsetY % scale * -1;

        if (form.HorizontalPosition != lastXPosition && form.VerticalPosition == lastYPosition)
            lastStartX += spacingX;
        else if (tab.HorizontalScroll.Value == lastXPosition && form.VerticalPosition != lastYPosition)
            lastStartY += spacingY;

        lastYPosition = form.VerticalPosition;
        lastXPosition = form.HorizontalPosition;

        for (int i = lastStartY; i < formHeight; i += scale)
            form.draw(0, i, formWidth, i);
        for (int i = lastStartX; i < formWidth; i += scale)
            form.draw(i, 0, i, formWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work for you:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        const int gridSpacing = 20;
        const int lineThickness = 1;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(gridSpacing, gridSpacing);
        using (System.Drawing.Pen pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Blue, lineThickness))
        {
            using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                G.Clear(this.BackColor);
                G.DrawLine(pen, 0, bmp.Height - pen.Width, bmp.Width, bmp.Height - pen.Width); // horizontal
                G.DrawLine(pen, bmp.Width - pen.Width, 0, bmp.Width - pen.Width, bmp.Height); // vertical
            }
        }

        foreach (TabPage TP in tabControl1.TabPages)
        {
            TP.BackgroundImage = bmp;
            TP.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Tile;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you just need it to align differently?...can you elaborate?  Maybe we can tweak it; or change your current approach somehow.